# ng-repeat + smart table don't render properly

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

i have am iterating smart table with angular like this:

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th ng-repeat="title in productColumnsTitle" class="text-center" st-sort="{{title.name}}">{{title.title}}</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

then i have other table below called without the ng-repeat attribute, but i see that all the columns are not well rendered it seems that width of this and tags are different from that below, anyone know why?

Comment: Add width property on columns of both table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `ng-repeat` in your table headers, the header is where you'll put you objects property names in the order you will want them to show

```
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
     <th>last name</th>
     <th>birth date</th>
     <th>balance</th>
     <th>email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

you can technically iterate the object properties using something like `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0]"`, but you will have no control over the order of the properties.

[just iterate over plain table rows](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGq29V?p=preview).

also, make sure you use the appropriate amount of cell width in your [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) `<td>` attribute